# Correct order for code in Front Controller?

Tags: php

I have a front controller which set-ups various elements within the page. However it occurred to me that perhaps some elements were not in the correct order; what I mean by this is that some elements may need to be used/declared prior to other elements.

Or, put another way: have I structured the file in the best/correct way. eg session_start() should come 'after' ini_set() and so on.

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);

$mytimeout = 720 * 60; // (12hrs*60m=720) // minutes * 60
session_set_cookie_params($mytimeout);

$sessdir = "../application/data"; 
ini_set('session.save_path', $sessdir);

session_cache_expire($mytimeout / 60);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $mytimeout);

session_start();

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

require_once('../application/models/front.php');
require_once('../application/models/icontroller.php');
require_once('../application/models/view.php');
require_once('../application/models/db.php');
require_once('../application/models/sconfig.php');
require_once('../application/models/acl.php');

require_once('../application/controllers/index.php');
require_once('../application/controllers/user.php');
require_once('../application/controllers/error.php');
require_once('../application/controllers/blog.php');
require_once('../application/controllers/about.php');

function exception_handler($exception) {
  echo "Sorry something went wrong; And or we couldnt find what you requested.<br />We suggest you go back to our <a href=\"/\">home page</a> and try again.<br />We have logged this request in order to provide a better service.<br /> *** ". $exception->getMessage()." ***";

}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

$fc = FrontController::getInstance();
$c=$fc->getController();
$a=$fc->getAction();

$users=ACL::getInstance();
$sid=session_id();

if(isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
  if($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
    $_SESSION=array();
    $users->removeUser($sid);
    if(($c!='error')&&($a!='badsession')){
      $fc->redirect("error/badsession");
    }
  }
}
else{
  $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
}   

$dbh=DBConnection::getInstance();

setcookie('ct', 1,0,"/");

$config = Configuration::getInstance();
$cf=array();
$cf=$config->getall();

$users=ACL::getInstance();
$users->addUser();
$users->removeOld();

$front = FrontController::getInstance();

$front->route();
echo $front->getBody();
```

Comment: Does your code work or does it generates an exception? BTW you have assigned a `FrontController` instance 3 times in the same script. Similar pattern for `ACL`.

Comment: @Bart code work's fine :) I was just wondering really if I have structured the file in the best way. eg session_start() should come 'after' ini_set() and so on. Yeah true, there are some redundant singletons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of things could be adjusted a tiny bit.
This would be the order I choose:

1. First off all I would place the `error_reporting` call at the top so you'll have everything reporting errors as expected.
2. Then set `exception_handler` and `exception_handler` so you can catch everything.
3. Do all the `ini_set` calls.
4. `require` all the necessary scripts.
5. Start the session with `session_start`. If all the above things went well.
6. Do the other logic.

**NOTE**

It's not a very good idea to use singletons. Especially in the volume you use them.
See here why that is [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)
It's better to unlearn the use of singletons. 
Singletons make you careless about code design and I'm sorry to say. It shows in your example :-)

Comment: yeah I read about bad practises re singletons from many sites; I guess its like Marmite, you either love it or hate it. lol :) Personally I think they implement composition perfectly. ** Your answer makes sense, although I am thinking that I should do session_start() before requiring anything?

Comment: If everything is contained in classes then **no**. I would first require and then start the session. Simply because it's not needed. If you might have code depending on a session wich could be executed when the script is included then **yes**